# Unable to update Virtual Machine Diagnostic sttings

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-storage, azure-diagnostics

As title said, unable to update Diagnostic Settings on a Virtual Machine

As I created, it got set up to every 5 seconds performance counters, that makes over 400Gb every month approx.

Normally I do not need this kind of diagnostics, so I try to change, doesn't matter what settings I try, always say "UPDATE FAILED" without further indication.

Comment: negative voting ??, editing the question??, do you mind explain why??  Microsoft state to ask question about Azure on StackOveflow, and MS bought this thing

Comment: See also: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/21307

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue, always say "update failed", and I will submit this issue to Microsoft.

I find a workaround, which can update the value even it says "update failed", steps as below:

**1.Go to the "Diagnostic settings" blade -> Performance counters -> basic, I want to set the Network's sample rate to 80(it is 60 by default):**

[image]

**2.Set the value to 80 -> click save, then wait for a while until the "update failed " occurs. But when you click the Notification, you can see that it says "update success"**

[image]

**3.Click the Notification -> then click the text "Successfully updated diagnostics settings" -> a popup window appears, just click ok button(if it appears more times, just click ok button):**

[image]

**4. After step 3, it will bring you to the overview blade. Just nav to the Diagnostics settings blade -> Performance counters -> basic, check the value, it's 80 now:**

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for response, 

it seems NOT working, in my case I have enabled plenty of "performance counters" and few "logs"

Comment: I have try changing values (seconds), I have try enabling and disabling options, I have try to change from Basic to Custom, once by once, plenty at once, ...

Comment: Nothing seems to take effect, and even no notification is raised. Just the "Update failed"

Comment: you mention " I will submit this issue to Microsoft." , is there a way to communicate this to MS ??

Comment: @pGrnd2, you can comment on this [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/21307), the MS said **it's a this is a known issue and the error should be ignored, there will be a fix deployed on the next few weeks**. Just follow up this issue if you have any questions.

Comment: @pGrnd2, if the issue I mentioned above cannot help you, please feel free to let me know. I can escalate this issue to MS by email.

Comment: i was just in phone with MS and ask for details to forward to especific team ...  I hope they get into the same group that cares for this ticket.  THANKS A LOT  (still do not get the negative voting :sad: )